# Unable to run cucumber tests from new tab on Mac terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal, tabs, cucumber

If I have run few cucumber tests on say, tab1, of a terminal window, I cant run cucumber tests on new tab. I get the following error. Also, if I open a new window and run the tests they work.

**Terminal Output**

```
BBCMAC:apigee-cucumber test$ bundle exec cucumber -p test -t @469
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000438
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin12.0]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0039 p:-17568156646234 s:0167 e:000166 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0038 p:---- s:0165 e:000164 CFUNC  :require
c:0037 p:0020 s:0161 e:000160 RESCUE /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:29
c:0036 p:0125 s:0158 e:000157 TOP    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:25 [FINISH]
c:0035 p:---- s:0156 e:000155 CFUNC  :require
c:0034 p:0039 s:0152 e:000151 BLOCK  /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86 [FINISH]
c:0033 p:---- s:0148 e:000147 CFUNC  :each
c:0032 p:0055 s:0145 e:000144 BLOCK  /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81 [FINISH]
c:0031 p:---- s:0139 e:000138 CFUNC  :each
c:0030 p:0032 s:0136 e:000135 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70
c:0029 p:0013 s:0132 e:000131 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102
c:0028 p:0019 s:0128 e:000127 TOP    /Users/test/Documents/apigee/apigee-cucumber/features/support/env.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0027 p:---- s:0125 e:000124 CFUNC  :load
c:0026 p:0018 s:0121 e:000120 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95
c:0025 p:0039 s:0117 e:000116 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180
c:0024 p:0009 s:0112 e:000111 BLOCK  /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83 [FINISH]
c:0023 p:---- s:0109 e:000108 CFUNC  :each
c:0022 p:0018 s:0106 e:000105 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82
c:0021 p:0027 s:0102 e:000101 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184
c:0020 p:0007 s:0098 e:000097 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42
c:0019 p:0070 s:0094 e:000093 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47
c:0018 p:0169 s:0087 e:000086 TOP    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/bin/cucumber:13 [FINISH]
c:0017 p:---- s:0085 e:000084 CFUNC  :load
c:0016 p:0135 s:0081 e:000080 TOP    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/bin/cucumber:23 [FINISH]
c:0015 p:---- s:0077 e:000076 CFUNC  :load
c:0014 p:0091 s:0073 e:000072 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63
c:0013 p:0058 s:0065 e:000064 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:24
c:0012 p:0028 s:0061 e:000060 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:304
c:0011 p:0066 s:0057 e:000056 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27
c:0010 p:0051 s:0050 e:000049 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126
c:0009 p:0272 s:0044 e:000043 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359
c:0008 p:0064 s:0032 e:000031 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440
c:0007 p:0010 s:0026 e:000025 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11
c:0006 p:0089 s:0021 e:000020 BLOCK  /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:27
c:0005 p:0006 s:0016 e:000015 METHOD /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98
c:0004 p:0048 s:0012 E:001178 TOP    /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:19 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0010 e:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0135 s:0006 E:000ec8 EVAL   /usr/local/bin/bundle:23 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000028 TOP    [FINISH]

/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:19:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/exe/bundle:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:304:in `exec'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:24:in `run'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/bin/cucumber:23:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load'
/Users/test/Documents/apigee/apigee-cucumber/features/support/env.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   libruby.2.1.0.dylib                 0x0000000108d129a8 rb_print_backtrace + 29
1   libruby.2.1.0.dylib                 0x0000000108d12a8f rb_vm_bugreport + 124
2   libruby.2.1.0.dylib                 0x0000000108c13904 report_bug + 307
3   libruby.2.1.0.dylib                 0x0000000108c137cc rb_bug + 180
4   libruby.2.1.0.dylib                 0x0000000108cb2a46 check_stack_overflow + 0
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8b69d90a _sigtramp + 26
6   libruby.2.1.0.dylib                 0x00000001096a4361 ruby_xmalloc + 17
7   ???                                 0x00007fff5701f7d0 0x0 + 140734653134800

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/bin/cucumber

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/rbconfig.rb
    4 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    5 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    6 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    7 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    8 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/version.rb
    9 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   10 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   11 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
   12 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
   13 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
   14 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   15 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   16 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
   17 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   ...............................0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/shell_command.rb
  505 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/shell_mode.rb
  506 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/show_info.rb
  507 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/show_doc.rb
  508 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/show_input.rb
  509 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/show_source.rb
  510 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/simple_prompt.rb
  511 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/stat.rb
  512 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/switch_to.rb
  513 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/toggle_color.rb
  514 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/watch_expression/expression.rb
  515 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/watch_expression.rb
  516 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/whereami.rb
  517 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands/wtf.rb
  518 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/commands.rb
  519 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/plugins.rb
  520 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/core_extensions.rb
  521 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/config/behavior.rb
  522 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/config/default.rb
  523 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/config/convenience.rb
  524 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/config.rb
  525 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_class.rb
  526 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb
  527 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/cli.rb
  528 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/coderay-1.1.0/lib/coderay/helpers/plugin.rb
  529 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/coderay-1.1.0/lib/coderay/encoder.rb
  530 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/coderay-1.1.0/lib/coderay/encoders/_map.rb
  531 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/coderay-1.1.0/lib/coderay/encoders/terminal.rb
  532 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/color_printer.rb
  533 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/terminal.rb
  534 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/pager.rb
  535 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/editor.rb
  536 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/rubygem.rb
  537 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/indent.rb
  538 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/last_exception.rb
  539 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/prompt.rb
  540 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/inspector.rb
  541 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/object_path.rb
  542 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/output.rb
  543 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry.rb
  544 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/array.rb
  545 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/string.rb
  546 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/method.rb
  547 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/object.rb
  548 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/class.rb
  549 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/kernel.rb
  550 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/inspector.rb
  551 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/formatter.rb
  552 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/version.rb
  553 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/logger.rb
  554 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print.rb
  555 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/relish-0.7/lib/relish/version.rb
  556 /Users/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@apigee/gems/relish-0.7/lib/relish.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

The error stack mentions env.rb:2 somewhere in between..

**env.rb:**

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
```

Comment: Did you compared the ruby version and other related environmental variables between the working and non-working terminals ? any difference ?

Comment: Nokogiri 1.6.3 had a few bugs causing seg faults. Try downgrading it to 1.6.1, and see if the problem still persists. Also, any difference in terminals as asked by radkris above ?

Comment: Similar to what @radkris said, are you using rvm or some other ruby version tool? You may need to switch to the gemset that includes cucumber.